# Set home routes to direct in Sinatra simple authentication

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra, datamapper, simple-authentication

I'm trying to use Sinatra simple auth to force users to logon before being able to access the site. So the home page would be the logon then should be able to use the site without being prompted for it. At the moment I could not figure out a way to redirect to the home root page after logon. set :home is working as it should.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Required gems
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'sinatra/simple-authentication'
require 'rack-flash'

# Required models and database
require './models/note'

class Index < Sinatra::Base
  DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
    DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/recall.db")


  use Rack::Flash, :sweep => true
  register Sinatra::SimpleAuthentication

    enable :sessions
    set :home, '/'

    # ** SHOW **
    # Root to the index page
    # Pull all notes from the DB into an instance varible to access from the index page in descends order.
    get '/' do
        login_required
      @notes = Note.all :order => :id.desc
      haml :index
    end

    # ** SAVE **
    # Retrieves note contents from :contents on the index view and save them into the DB.
    # Redirects back to the index page.
    post '/' do
      n = Note.new
      n.content = params[:content]
      n.created_at = Time.now
      n.updated_at = Time.now
      n.save
        redirect '/'
    end


    # ** EDIT **
    # Retrieves notes ID to edit the note
    # Title varible is to display the note ID to the user to be able to edit/delete a specific note.
    get '/:id' do
        @note = Note.get params[:id]
        @title = "Edit note ##{params[:id]}"
        haml :edit
    end

    # Edit
    # Retrieves the saved note for the user to edit then save it with the same ID and new timestamp
    put '/:id' do
        n = Note.get params[:id]
        n.content = params[:content]
        n.complete = params[:complete] ? 1 : 0
        n.updated_at = Time.now
        n.save
        redirect '/'
    end

    # ** DESTROY **
    # Delete note by the ID
    # Retrun the note ID to the view page to confirm the deletion of the right note.
    get '/:id/delete' do
        @note = Note.get params[:id]
        @title = "Confirm deletion of note ##{params[:id]}"
        haml :delete
    end

    # Delte note by ID
    delete '/:id' do
        n = Note.get params[:id]
        n.destroy
        redirect '/'
    end

    # Check the completion of note (still not working)
    get '/:id/complete' do
        n = Note.get params[:id]
        n.complete = n.complete ? 0 : 1 # flip it
        n.updated_at = Time.now
        n.save
        redirect '/'
    end

    # To resturn the "Page not found" insted of the default Sinatra error page.
    not_found do
      halt 404, "Page not found 404"
    end
end
**strong text**
```

Comment: Please remove extra code from your post. We don't need to see all of that. Also, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for help, unfortunately this created an infinite loop. To make it clear I don't want the user to be able to do anything without login first (not even viewing the index page)

Comment: But the user has to log in first right? They have to access the login route.

Comment: Thats right, So you mean that the  ' / ' should direct to the logon view right?. The thing is that Sinatra simple authentication gem doesn't give me access to its routes to modify them (or I don't know how). If you look at this is the solution I'm trying to implement into my site  https://github.com/vast/sinatra-simple-auth

Comment: Looks like you need to write a login form yourself

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is check if a user is logged in before any routes except "/" you can use this:

```
before do
    if request.path != "/"
        if # statement which returns false if a user is logged in
            redirect "/"
        end
    end
end
```